# PDF file content to Base 64 and vice versa in Java

Tags: java, pdf, base64

I need to convert PDF content to Base64 and use that as a String.
When I use the below program to test the out.pdf becomes blank.

```
    byte[] pdfRawData =  FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("C:\\in.pdf")) ;
    String pdfStr = new String(pdfRawData);

//My data is available in the form of String

    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    String encodedPdf = encoder.encode(pdfStr.getBytes());
    System.out.println(encodedPdf);


// Decode the encoded content to test


    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();        
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:\\out.pdf") , decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedPdf));
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you doing:

```
String pdfStr = new String(pdfRawData);
```

instead of passing pdfRawData to the encoder?

Doing so lead to lots of encoding issue, as you don't specify the encoding of the byte array to use to build the string (it will use platform default). And this is clearly redondant (byte array -> string -> byte array)

Comment: The pdf content will be available in the form of String and not file as the pdf will be generate on runtime. I need to convert this string pdf to Base64 String. This is just a test program to simulate.

Comment: Can't you generate the document and store it in a byte array instead of a string? Are you the one generating the document? Storing raw binary data in a string is a code smell - not all bytes sequences are valid in a given string encoding (base64 encoding was designed to address this issue). Anyway, try specifying the encoding in both your constructor and getBytes() method (eg. "UTF-8").

Comment: I will receive these PDF's via a webservice in the form of String that is the reason I am reading the file in bytes and converting to back to String to encode it.
I tried adding 
String encodedPdf = encoder.encode(pdfStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
but getting a long document than usual with empty content. The strange thing I am able to render the PDF without any issues.

Comment: *"I will receive these PDF's via a webservice in the form of String"* - A PDF handled as String usually automatically is damaged beyond repair unless the PDF was specifically created to be compatible with text handling (in which case the file usually also is damaged but not beyond repair). Please inspect your webservice API and check whether there is a way to retrieve the PDF in a binary form (as `byte[]`, as `ByteBuffer`, as `InputStream`, ...).

Comment: Makes sense....I am now receiving the PDF base 64 encoded via webservice as a String. I was able to reproduce this pdf by decoding and writing it to a file. String pdfb64encodedData = "sdjhjsbdvbjsbsbdvbjsdbvbsvbsvb...."; FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:\\out.pdf"), decoder.decodeBuffer(pdfb64encodedData));.......Thanks for your response